# How to import an image sequence?

Tags: image, movie-clip-editor

I have a collection of images that I want to import into the movie clip editor as an image sequence. The problem is that it only showed one image in one frame (1/1 instead of 1/22).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a little bug: to solve, when importing your image sequence, you have to sort your files by name.

[image]

Comment: It works now, thanks!